# sorting string according to their length using mergesort

Tags: python, string, sorting, mergesort

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/merge-sort/practice-problems/algorithm/i-think-its-easy/

the merge sort algorithm is working fine and i am able to get the same string as expected, however the output is not matching with the expected output.

```
n = int(raw_input())
a = []  # input list
for i in range(n):
    a.append(raw_input().split())
for i in range(n):
    print (' '.join(mergesort(a[i])
```

in the expected output for each new list of strings one extra space is present in the beginning while my code do not add any extra space at the beginning of new list of strings. why is this difference present when only one space is to be printed between two strings? how can i solve this?

my output : [my_output](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/userdata/1429023/hackathon/ThreeMusketeers/code/output-16072656-137792534-599e26d.txt)
expected output : [expected_output](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/ThreeMusketeers/problems/0a8c244011-out08.txt?Signature=tTBWmZh43HMXepaQLvPcmX%2FjJh8%3D&Expires=1522599210&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDRXK3ZWDNTBIPQA)

below is the required output format, hence i added the space  in my print function in last line .

Output:

The output should contain the set of input strings ordered by the length of strings.A blank space must be printed between two words.

Comment: that is because, you are adding a space in your last print statement

Comment: that space is added because for each list of strings i want a space between the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit confused to me. Do you really want `raw_input().split()`? I don't think so. Try this:

```
inp = raw_input()
for el in inp.split():
    print(''.join(mergesort(el)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the join functio wring. It merges the array into a string, separating the elements by the string on which you are calling it. In your case the space. If you want spaces at the front and the end of your string, you have to do this by hand.

```
print(' ', ' '.join(mergesort(a[i])))
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: the problem is my code is working fine with the sample test case. only when i do submit and it's checked with other cases that extra space is coming in picture. if i add the way you told me the sample test case fails

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't checked the link. They don't want you to put spaces in front of the lines. So my code isn't right. Where do you get your expected output from? Are you sure that your mergesort works correctly? What should happen when two strings have the  same length, maybe your error is at that point.

Comment: if two strings had same length then the one which appears earlier will be printed first that's what they want  also. output  difference for case 9. https://www.hackerearth.com/problems/output_diff/112287606/